# Metrizable Space and continuous extension function

Tags: general-topology

Let A be a closed subspace of a metrizable space $X$, then for every continuous function $f:A\rightarrow I$ and every metric $\rho$ on the space $X$ , I want to show that the formula

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \inf \left\{f(a)+\frac{\rho(x,a)}{\rho(x,A)}-1: a\in A \right\}, & \textrm{ if $x\in X\backslash A $ ,} \\\\
      f(x), & \textrm{ if $x\in A$}, \\
   \end{cases}$$

define a continuous extension $F$ of $f$ over $X$.

<s>Remark:- What I know I have to use [TIETZE-URYSOHN THEOREM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem),which states:-</s>

Every continuous function from a closed subspace $M$ of a normal space $X$ to $I$ or $\mathbb{R}$ is continuously extendable over $X$.
.

From the comment I figure out this remark is not useful.

Comment: You don't have to use Tietze. You have to show that $F$ is continuous, then you have an explicit extension of $f$, while Tietze/Urysohn only gives existence [and the proof a way to construct one, but very cumbersome]. This shows that metric spaces are particularly nice.

Comment: Now, I understand we don't need to use the Tietze/Urysohn theorem. thanks

Comment: Historical aside: this extension formula first appeared in 1919 paper by Hausdorff, following the 1915 paper by Tietze from which the extension result originates (although Tietze proved it for metric spaces only). [References here](http://calculus7.org/2012/04/19/tietze-and-hausdorff-extension-formulas/)

Comment: More importantly, I think you have to assume $f$ is bounded from below. For example, suppose $A$ is the closed unit ball of a Hilbert space: then there is a continuous real-valued $f$ with $\inf_A f= -\infty$, hence $F(x)\equiv -\infty$ according to this definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this extension to work, $f$ must be assumed bounded from below. Indeed, if $A$ is the $x$-axis of $\mathbb R^2$ and $f(x,0)=-x^2$ , the extension gives $F(x)=-\infty$ for every $x\in \mathbb R^2\setminus A$. Such examples exist even if $A$ is a bounded closed set.

The idea of this formula is that even though the infimum allows $a$ to be any point of $A$, the "far-away" points have large ratio $\rho(x,a)/\rho (x,A)$ which effectively drops them from the competition for the infimum.  In contrast, when $a$ is an almost-nearest point of $A$ to $x$, we have $\rho(x,a)\approx \rho(x,A)$ and so the "penalty" $\frac{\rho(x,a)}{\rho(x,A)}-1$ drops down to nearly zero.

#### Continuity at $x_0\in X\setminus A$

Focus on  the ball of radius $\frac12 \rho(x_0,A)$ centered at $x_0$. Within this ball, $\rho(x,A)\ge \frac12 \rho(x_0,A)$. The ratio of two Lipschitz continuous functions is Lipschitz continuous, provided that the denominator is bounded away from $0$. More precisely,  the function 
$$
g_a(x) = f(a)+\frac{\rho(x,a)}{\rho(x,A)}-1
$$
is Lipschitz on this ball with constant $4/\rho(x_0,A)$, independent of $a$. Taking the infimum preserves this property.

#### Continuity at $x_0\in  A$

Given $\epsilon>0$, take $R>0$ such that $|f(a)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ when $\rho(a,x_0)<R$. If $x\notin A$ and $\rho(x,x_0)<r\ll R$ ($r$ much smaller than $R$), then every point  $a\in A$ with $\rho(a,x_0)\ge R$ has 
$$
f(a)+\frac{\rho(x,a)}{\rho(x,A)}-1 \ge \inf_A f+\frac{R}{r}-1
$$
So, choose $r$ small enough so that 
$$\inf_A f+\frac{R}{r}-1> f(x_0) $$
Use this to conclude that $F(x)\ge f(x_0)-\epsilon$ when $\rho(x,x_0)<r$.

The inequality $F(x)\le f(x_0)+\epsilon$ follows by considering $a\in A$ such that $\rho(x,a)/\rho(x,A)$ is very close to $1$; note that such $a$ will be within $B(x_0,R)$.